# How to prevent MVC Core to add some undesired packages while creating a new controller in ASP.Net MVC Core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, scaffolding

I am working on a new ASP.Net MVC Core 2.1.2 project, target .Net 4.7.2 (so not .Net Core). 
When I add a new Controller by a right click on Controllers folder, "Add", "Controller", my new controller is successfully created almost empty, as expected :

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

But there are also some dependencies silently added to my project :

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.1.0">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.0" />
```

I don't care about the last one, but I can't figure why it also adds EF Core, and I would like to avoid it, especially because my back end assemblies referenced in the project are already using Entity Framework, but in its version 6.x (not Core).

Why does it behave like this, and can it be avoided ? Thanks

FYI, of course I know I could simply add my new controllers as "new classes" and inherit from Controller, without to use "Add controller" stuff, to avoid this problem but I would like to understand what happens here.

Answer (score 1):

I remmember having the same issue as well while creating similar project setups (.Net Core apps targeting .net 4.*).

I believe this is related to the scaffolding that you get while adding controllers via the context menu you mentioned.
What you could do to avoid receiving those dependencies is to create the controllers as regular c# classes and add the boilerplate code yourself (= inheriting fom the controller base class and adding the using statements required.)

I am not aware of any other possibility of getting the scaffolding to work without those dependencies.

Comment: Of course I know about the obvious workaround. But as it's a team project (so somebody will end up by use the generator and wrongly checkin the offending references) and code generation can be useful for some case (quickly generate matching view for a specific class, etc) I was hoping to find a way to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1):

> OP: FYI, of course I know I could simply add my new controllers as
>   "new classes" and inherit from Controller, without to use "Add
>   controller" stuff, to avoid this problem but I would like to
>   understand what happens here.

**Why these dependencies are drawn inside the project**

Those dependencies are added by base scaffolder class of the controller scaffolder.

The dependencies are defined in a config file named `MvcCoreScaffoldingConfig.json` which is located in `Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Scaffolding` folder under the Visual Studio installation folder. For me I found it the following folder:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Scaffolding\
```

**Can I prevent adding those dependencies?**

You can change or remove the dependencies defined in the config file. For example, just for test, I removed the following dependencies from `"NetStandard20Packages"` array and after *closing and reopening VS*, I added a `Controller` and it didn't add those dependencies:

- "PackageId": "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design"
- "PackageId": "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer"
- "PackageId": "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools"

If you remove those dependencies, the following scaffolding templates will stop working, since they have dependencies to EntityFrameworkCore:

- MVC Controller with views, using Entity Framework
- API Controller with actions, using Entity Framework

In a ASP.NET Core project which uses .NET Framework and Entity Framework 6, above controller scaffoldings are not useful, so you don't need to be worried about removing those dependencies. Removing those dependencies, doesn't have any impact on view scaffoldings.

Comment: Even if you don't remove those dependencies, since the namespaces and classes of Entity Framework Core which are in the installed packages are different from Entity Framework 6 classes and namespaces and you don't use them, I guess those packages will be harmless for your project. After all, pull requests are good mechanism to prevent a branch from getting merged with the main branch in case it's not following conventions (not using controller scaffolding.).

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much. I have no time now to verify what you said but as you are the first to post a true answer in regards of my needs and as the bounty expires in a few hours I awarded it to you. I'll check technical aspects later.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a controller, the visual studio will check your project dependencies. As you said, you created a ASP.Net MVC Core 2.1.2 project, so VS will check the dependencies for that version and will add them to the project.

If you want to prevent VS from doing the checking, then you could add a class and make it extends from a controller.